# How to reference derived values in other areas of MySQL select statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I am trying to calculate a special score. The 'total' and the 'correct' (or `order`) need different queries to get, and the total will need to be used in two places. This led to issues with use of aliases. Repeating a sub-query is too expensive in performance and readability in this case. I tried two different ways to get it working:

```
SELECT rankings.id as link, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM rankings
  INNER JOIN ranking_data ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
  WHERE case_id = 15 AND rankings.id = link
) as total,
ROUND(((total - `order`) / total) * 100, 2) AS score FROM rankings
INNER JOIN ranking_data ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND opinion_id = 124 AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
WHERE case_id = 15 AND user_id != 3;
```

Here I tried to create an alias for the 'total' value returned by the sub-query and use it in a calculation for scoring. The link reference worked within the sub-query, but the total reference failed in line 6.

```
SELECT ROUND(((total - `order`) / total) * 100, 2) AS score FROM rankings
INNER JOIN ranking_data ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND opinion_id = 124 AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM rankings
  INNER JOIN ranking_data ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
  WHERE case_id = 15
) AS total_table ON total_table.id = rankings.id
WHERE case_id = 15 AND user_id != 3;
```

Here I tried to make the total available to the column list area for scoring by left joining a derived table. MySQL told me total_table.id was not found, in line 7. If I tried a left join, it would throw a general syntax error.

Can you give me a solution, and shed light on why the other attempts did not work?

Comment: please tell us what is your table structure with some example data on http://sqlfiddle.com and what you want display it

Comment: Sure if needed, but I think you might misunderstand the question. Its a question about syntax and how aliases may be used - the values shown in the WHERE clauses are just sample values

Comment: instead of using joins use derieved tables in joins this will give you command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query, `id` has not been explicitly included in the set of columns selected in the `total_table` inline view; you will probably also need to group by `id`. Try changing the query to:

```
SELECT ROUND(((total - `order`) / total) * 100, 2) AS score 
FROM rankings
INNER JOIN ranking_data 
ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND opinion_id = 124 AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT rankings.id, COUNT(*) as total FROM rankings
  INNER JOIN ranking_data 
  ON ranking_id = rankings.id AND `type` = 'pre_reference'
  WHERE case_id = 15
  GROUP BY rankings.id
) AS total_table 
ON total_table.id = rankings.id
WHERE case_id = 15 AND user_id != 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! That did solve the error on the last query. I didn't have that problem in top-level sql queries. Is it a quirk of sub-queries?

Comment: It's an inherent part of queries - the columns that are returned are the ones that are explicitly included within the select statement, regardless of whether it is inside a sub-query, or is part of the main query.

Comment: Ok. Any idea about the first query?

Comment: Yes - total is only defined in the resultset for the main query, not in the tables being joined, so it can't be used to derive other items in the select clause. You could turn the main query (without score) into a sub-query, then derive score in a select from your new sub-query.

Comment: I found that there are some more issues with the second query, which seems the closest to getting this to work. In the derived table sub-query, I am trying to get the count of all the records that match the rankings.id in the current result set. So, I need to match the IDs together AND get a count on the multiple rows returned.

If I select a count in the sub-query, it doesn't select by ID properly because it only returns one id along with the count. If I return all the results then do a count in the calculations, it doesn't return the multiple scores its supposed to.

Comment: Is there any way we could chat? This is part of a project and I would really appreciate a resolution.

Comment: We can use this chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16348/discussion-between-mark-bannister-and-waffles